# Header File Doesn't Recognize typedef from a Different Header File

Tags: c, eclipse, typedef

Right now I'm working on a project for my course on system programming. We were asked to program an apartment selling platform, with Realtors and Customers. I'm working on Eclipse.

Now, even though I didn't experience any problems like that in the past, one of my header files fails to recognize a typedef from a second header file.

Explanation: here are my files;

Realtor.h

```
#include "apartment.h"
#include "apartment_service.h"
#include "Report.h"
#include "Customer.h"
#include "mtm_ex2.h"


typedef struct realtor_t* Realtor;
```

While this is the second header file;

Customer.h

```
#include "Report.h"
#include "Realtor.h"
#include "apartment.h"
#include "apartment_service.h"
#include "mtm_ex2.h"

typedef struct customer_t* Customer;

MtmErrorCode purchaseApartment (Customer customer, Realtor realtor,
        ApartmentService service,
        int apartment_id);

MtmErrorCode makeOffer (Customer customer, Realtor realtor, ApartmentService
        service, int apartment_id, int new_price);
```

(the structs of customer_t and realtor_t are defined in the source files)

For some reason, the function declarations in Customer.h give me the following error: "unknown type name 'Realtor'". This is really weird because the same functions use other typedefs like 'ApartmentService' from "apartment_service.h".

Comment: I am missing some include guards, because you have circular inclusion in your header. Do you have these guards, just to shoot out these first errors.

Comment: To add to that: Even with guards, `Customer.h` includes `Realtor.h` which includes `Customer.h`, which includes (a probably guarded) `Realtor.h`. Without include guards, this does not work at all. With include guards, the second include of `Realtor.h` just goes through and you end up in `Customer.h` without any of the declarations of `Realtor.h` (because you are actually processing exactly that include).

Answer (score 3):

You are including Customer.h in Realtor.h.

This is where the error is occurring. In Realtor.h, the typedef for `Realtor` is not defined before Customer.h

Remove the inclusion of Customer.h from Realtor.h. That should solve the problem for the code given.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. Any more ideas maybe?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You simply shouldn't do this. You should include these include files in your code files, not your include files.

Having declarations like `typedef struct customer_t* Customer;` in your header files is fine. You don't need such a declaration to know anything more as you are defining a pointer to some type. That is all the compiler needs to know for the prototypes you give.

EDIT

Each module should only export what it makes available and the total should "build up" so there are preferably no circular dependencies. So Apartment is for example a base "class", Apartment Services uses Apartment; Customer is a base "class", and your program has functions for a Customer to buy an Apartment. Sometimes circuar references or forward references can't be prevented. In that case you should use "include guards" that ensure the contents of an include file is included only once.

```
/* apartment.h */
#ifndef APT_INCLUDED
#define APT_INCLUDED
typedef struct Apartment* tApartmemt;
tApartment NewApartment(char * name);
#endif /*APT_INCLUDED*/

/* apartment_services.h */
#ifndef APTSVC_INCLUDED
#define APTSVC_INCLUDED
#include "apartment.h"
typedef struct ApartmentService* tAptSvc;
tAptSvc NewAptSvc(tApartment apartment, char *svcname);
#endif /*APTSVC_INCLUDED*/
```

Taking a good look at who needs to know about what may simplify your include structure too, for example, I doubt that `makeOffer` should be part of the customer module and as a result the module should not need to include apartment or realtor; rather, it is the realtor that makes the offer. I also note that your includes seem a bit in random order. Anyway, using the include guards can prevent circular includes and should solve you original problem. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: So how I should I do function declarations in my .h file? For example the function I'm trying to declare there makes use of ApartmentService from ApartmentService.h and Realtor from Realtor.h. If I don't include them in my .h, how can I use them in my function declaration? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Put the `typedef struct realtor_t* Realtor;` line right before the include of `Customer.h` in your `Realtor.h` header file.